# I don't understand how to differentiate this multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

To solve part of a problem I need to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(tx,ty)$. It's also given that $f(tx,ty)=t^n f(x,y)$ for some integer $n$. Yet I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I know I *have to use the chain rule*, instead of just evaluating  $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} t^n f(x,y) = nt^{n-1} f(x,y)$. Since they will probably lead to different (but equivilent) expressions  which can help me prove that
$$
x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=nf(x,y)
$$

My attempt consisted of letting $u=tx$ and $v=ty$. Then all I have to do is differentiate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(u,v)$ which by the chain rule gives
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=x\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}
$$

And now I'm stuck. It should be the case that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = t^{n-1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ (and a similar thing for $y$) since these would lead me to the conclusion. At this point, I feel like I've done something wrong but I'm not sure how else to approach this.

Also, note that I don't want help with actually solving the problem, I just need a nudge in the right direction or a hint. And the hint I want is to evaluate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(tx,ty)$.

Comment: Questions about Euler's Theorem on homogeneous functions have been discussed on this website many times. you may find some of those earlier discussions helpful. Here's one; there are many others. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781396/eulers-theorem-on-homogeneous-functions-proof-question

Comment: @GerryMyerson this was an exercise in my calc textbook so I'm not familiar much of whats in that post

Comment: You are pretty much done, since the derivative w.r.t. the first arguments is usually called $\partial/\partial x$ instead of $\partial/\partial u$, and so on. My hint for you is do not suppress the arguments of the functions (i.e. keep writing out $f_x(tx,ty)$ or $f_x(x,y)$ as the situation may have it). What happens, after taking derivatives on both sides of the expression $f(tx,ty) = t^nf(x,y)$, you plug in $t=1$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you, now the solution looks obvious yet I spent a ridiculous amount of time on this. god i need to sleep

Comment: As I wrote, there are many questions discussing the theorem. I just linked to one of them, and you just looked at that one, instead of searching farther.